# GPS Provider unknown error in Set Mock Location?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, gps, location

I'm trying to set my mock location however, I am getting the following error(Provider 'gps' unknown) and not to sure what is wrong?

I've got all the permission declared in my manifest.xml along with all the parameters.

**Mock Location Method**

```
 //Initiates the method to set the phones location
        private void setMockLocation() {
          mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
          mLocationManager.addTestProvider
                    (
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    "requiresNetwork" == "",
                    "requiresSatellite" == "",
                    "requiresCell" == "",
                    "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
                    "supportsAltitude" == "",
                    "supportsSpeed" == "",
                    "supportsBearing" == "",

                    android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                    android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
                    );

            Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            newLocation.setLatitude (32.4276462);
            newLocation.setLongitude(-23.5509257);

            newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            true
                    );

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                            null,
                            System.currentTimeMillis()
                    );

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
                    (
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            newLocation
                    );
        }
```

**Error message**

> ```
> 5-09 16:28:45.577    9070-9070/com.example.ankhit.saveme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
>             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
>             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
>             at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.removeTestProvider(ILocationManager.java:956)
>             at android.location.LocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.java:1194)
>             at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.setMockLocation(UserLocation.java:215)
>             at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.access$000(UserLocation.java:41)
>             at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation$4.onClick(UserLocation.java:173)
>             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
>             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18398)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Any ideas?